# Why is underaccent symbol not centered?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, stacking-symbols, tensor

Here's a MWE showing my issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{equation}
    A = e_{\underaccent{\dot}{0}}^0 \: e_0^{\dot{0}} \: \tensor{T}{^{\dot{0}}_{\underaccent{\dot}{0}}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

As you can see on the picture above, the under dot isn't well placed relative to its 0 symbol, while it is the case for the upper dot.  Why?  How can I solve this centering issue?

This centering issue is more obvious when using "1" instead of "0".

Comment: It occurs because it is expecting the accent to occur on an italic glyph that possesses a measure of slant (numerals possess no slant).  Not sure how to fix without using an alternate approach, such as `\underset{\dot{}}{0}`.

Comment: Apparently, adding \mathrm around it solves the issue.

Comment: Very nice "fix"!

Comment: You should consider answering your own question.  I would give it an upvote.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possible fix, using the command \mathrm :

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{equation}
    A = e_{\mathrm{\underaccent{\dot}{0}}}^0 \: e_0^{\dot{0}} \: \tensor{T}{^{\dot{0}}_{\mathrm{\underaccent{\dot}{0}}}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Maybe there's a better method in writing a small accent under a math symbol?

Answer (score 1):

In the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, you can declare the Unicode combining dot-below accent with `\DeclareUnicodeAccent`, although it is only usable in text mode:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DeclareUnicodeAccent{\dotbelow}{TU}{"0323}
\newcommand\zerodot{\mathord{\text{\normalfont\dotbelow{0}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
    A = e_{\zerodot}^0 \: e_0^{\dot{0}} \: T^{\dot{0}}_{\zerodot}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

Unfortunately, this is not compatible with `tensor`.  You might try `tensind` instead.